# Check first show up of code block in GIT

Tags: git, search, history

I would like to add `@since` params to my docblocks of class methods, how I can easily find first commit that have introduced that given method in class (not last modified like with `git blame` ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `git log -S'line of code here'`

You can enter multiple lines of code between the quotes if you wish, and customise log output in all the usual ways (`--oneline`, `-p` etc.), and the command will also work with `git diff` and `git format-patch`.

Comment: +1. See also this thread as an illustration of such a search. http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg147443.html